# Avoiding problems arising from having only images and no text as links for website navigation

Tags: html, css, image, navigation, seo

The website I'm making is for an author/illustrator and she wants words in the navigation bar to be written in her own handwriting, so the links in the navigation bar and her own name, which serves as the title, are all in the form of pictures rather than text.

Similarly, the homepage consists of some of her illustrations, each accompanied by a handwritten link, so that there is no text at all. I'm starting to realise from reading online that this may be seen as 'bad practise', so I want to ask those with more experience than me: how problematic is the lack of text?

I am not too worried about loading times and such - I've managed to make the image files quite small - but more things concerning accessibility and whether the site will appear in search engines.

And are there any ways I can avoid problems whilst still using the handwriting?

Comment: You can utilize `alt` and `title` attributes on the images for accessibility concerns. Alternatively you can create your own custom font with her actual handwriting. This is tedious but certainly possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, people who do not see images (for one reason or another) will find the site almost impossible to navigate, unless the `img` elements have `alt` attributes. Correctly written `alt` attributes resolve this problem and can be expected to provide adequate information to search engines as well. Second, people who use normal graphic browsers will see the texts in a specific appearance. This may mean that they find it less legible than normal text, perhaps even illegible. This greatly depends on the style of the text, including size and the contrast between text and background color.

If a downloadable font were used instead, via `@font-face`, then the latter problem would in principle be less severe, since users could disable page fonts and see the text in their preferred font. This is rather theoretical, though, and creating a font is nontrivial and probably not worth the effort here.

On the practical side, write the `alt` attributes and ask the author consider whether the font is legible enough to all visitors, including people with eyesight problems. It’s up to the author to decide whether the reduction in usability and accessibility is justified by the artistic impression made.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use images as navigation elements and are concerned about SEO and accessibility, you can use the alt-tag which you should use anyways.

Example:

```
<img src='images/nav1.png' alt='Home' />
```

Screenreaders and search engines use these tags to deal with images which they of course can not read.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose from many handwritting fonts and link them via `@font-face`.

If she wants to use her 'font', use images (ideally one image - looking for `sprite`) and put text underneath - it's call `image replacement`.

Comment: I assume you are suggesting adding the images through css as `background-image` rather than in html as an `img` as I have been doing, but in that case I wouldn't be able to use the `alt` attribute as the other answerers have suggested. I've now looked up image replacement and found lots of very nice tricks that use css but I can't see how any of them are more effective than a simple `img` element and `alt` text - what's the problem with doing that?? I must be missing something...

Comment: With image replacement you can better (unlimitely) style fallback. ALT has only a few options how to style that. The second advantage is that you don't see the 'image loading failed' icon and 'border' which takes a width and size of image.